# Need help reducing triple for loop to increase efficiency

Tags: java, for-loop, performance

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 7; ++k) {
        for (int h = i; h < 4 + i; ++h) {
            result = state.getAt(k, h);
            if (result == 1) {
                ++firstpl;
            }
            if (result == 2) {
                ++secondpl;
            }
            if (firstpl > 0 && secondpl > 0) {
                break;
            }
            //y = k;
        }
        if (firstpl == 0 && secondpl == 0) {
            break;
        } else if (firstpl > secondpl) {
            score += firstpl * firstpl;
            //if(state.getHeightAt(y)-3 < 3) score += 3+firstpl*2;
        } else {
            score -= secondpl * secondpl;
            //if(state.getHeightAt(y)-3 < 3) score -= 3+secondpl*2;
        }

        firstpl = 0;
        secondpl = 0;
    }
}
```

basically I have a 7 by 6 grid. I am going through 7 columns and looking at every 4 consecutive blocks vertically. Since there is 6 blocks upward. There is 3 four consecutive block for each column. State.getAt(k,h) takes in a x and y and returns a value.

Comment: In order to help make this more efficient, we'd need to know a bit more context. For example, what is the ultimate goal of this computation? That would help us suggest alternative ways to achieve the same goal. Additionally, why do you need to make this faster? Are you calling this code it many times for different values of `state` or are you calling it a few times but one of the operations in the code (e.g. `state.getAt()`) is expensive? If the latter, then it would be better to focus on reducing the number of expensive operations required (e.g. through a memoization approach, perhaps).

Comment: Why do you need to improve the efficiency of this?  It doesn't look like it would take much time at all. Have you measured / profiled it?

Comment: It being called in a Min_Max function so it will be called many times. I am only allowed a number of milliseconds for it to produce the score. To be exact it is in the evaluation function.

Comment: For the ultimate goal adds the score of every 4 consecutive block and returns it.

Comment: Sry to comment again. To clarify, state is the 7x6 grid. getAt() takes a x value and y value and returns either a 0,1,or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can improve on this, unless you can figure out an alternative representation for this "state" that allows this computation to be performed incrementally.

And since you have failed to properly explained what the state or the calculation actually mean, it is difficult for anyone but you to figure out whether an alternative approach is even feasible.  (And I for one am not going to attempt to reverse engineer the meaning from your code.)

---

OK.  For Connect4, the win / lose is a line of 4 checkers horizontally, vertically or diagonally in the 7x6 grid.  So what you could do is represent the score-state as an array of counters, corresponding to each of the columns, rows and diagonals in which a winning line could be made.  (7 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 20 of them => 20 counters)  Then construct a static mapping from an (x,y) position to the indexes of lines that pass through that.  When you add a checker at point (x,y) you look up the counters and increment them.  When you remove a checker ... decrement.

I'm not sure how that relates to your existing scoring function ... but then I don't see how that function relates to a strategy that would win the game.  Either way, you could *potentially* use the approach above to calculate scores incrementally.

Comment: The state is the board of the game Connect 4. I am looking at each slot to see if there is a 1 in a row, 2 in a row, 3 in a row. I assign values based on that and sum it up.